# how convert data to string in django templae

Tags: django, templates

I have a trouble in my django template, the below code don't work

```
<td>
  {% if product.size %}
    {% for size in product.size.__str()__.split(",") %}
        <span style="border:1px solid red;"> {{size}} </span>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</td>
```

what can I do to work my code ?

Comment: What's in product.size and why you need to convert it to string ?

Comment: I use below field in my object: ``` size = MultiSelectField(choices=SIZE_CHOICES)```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the templatetags?
[enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/)

You can also use the model methods:

[enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#model-methods)

Answer (score 0):

This

```
product.size.__str()__.split(",")
```

is not really nice in a template.
Split it up in the view and iterate through that.
Easiest point in a class based view is the get_centext_data

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['sizes'] = Product.objects.value_list('size', flat=true)
    return context
```

Then your template will simply become:

```
<td>
  {% if sizes %}
    {% for size in sizes %}
        <span style="border:1px solid red;"> {{size}} </span>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</td>
```